# Error 403 - Access denied using Spring security - ManyToMany annotation issue?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, many-to-many

I haven't been able to figure out what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to access the page /user/test.jsp but I am having an error 403 access denied error.

I guess the problem is coming from the ManyToMany annotations in the UserEntity class. I have tried everything I could but am still not successful in solving this.

After further research, it appears that the user_security_role are not loaded from the DB.

I know it is the case since the following portion of code in the buildUserFromUserEntity in the Assembler class return an empty SecurityRoleCollection:

```
for (SecurityRoleEntity role : userEntity.getSecurityRoleCollection()) {
    authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getName()));
}
```

Here are the SQL I used for the table (from the tutorial):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS security_role (

    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )

    ENGINE = InnoDB

    AUTO_INCREMENT = 4

    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (

    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

    `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

    `family_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

    `dob` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

    `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

    `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

    `confirm_password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

    `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,

    UNIQUE INDEX `username` (`username` ASC) )

    ENGINE = InnoDB

    AUTO_INCREMENT = 9

    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_security_role (

    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,

    `security_role_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `security_role_id`) ,

    INDEX `security_role_id` (`security_role_id` ASC) ,

    CONSTRAINT `user_security_role_ibfk_1`

    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )

    REFERENCES `user` (`id` ),

    CONSTRAINT `user_security_role_ibfk_2`

    FOREIGN KEY (`security_role_id` )

    REFERENCES `security_role` (`id` ))

    ENGINE = InnoDB

    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Here is the tricky part I can't get to work:
The annotations configured for the private Set securityRoleCollection; attribute do not load the data from the DB, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

```
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "family_name")
    private String familyName;

    @Column(name = "dob")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "confirm_password")
    private String confirmPassword;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @JoinTable(name = "user_security_role", joinColumns = {

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {

    @JoinColumn(name = "security_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<SecurityRoleEntity> securityRoleCollection;

    public UserEntity() {

    }
```

Here is my UserEntityDAOImpl class:

```
public class UserEntityDAOImpl implements UserEntityDAO {

    public UserEntity findByName(String username) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        UserEntity user = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            user = (UserEntity)session.createQuery("select u from UserEntity u where u.username = '"
                    + username + "'").uniqueResult();

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Here is the SecurityRoleEntity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "security_role", catalog = "userauth", schema = "")
@NamedQueries({

        @NamedQuery(name = "SecurityRoleEntity.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM SecurityRoleEntity s"),

        @NamedQuery(name = "SecurityRoleEntity.findById", query = "SELECT s FROM SecurityRoleEntity s WHERE s.id = :id"),

        @NamedQuery(name = "SecurityRoleEntity.findByName", query = "SELECT s FROM SecurityRoleEntity s WHERE s.name = :name") })
public class SecurityRoleEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "securityRoleCollection", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserEntity> userCollection;

    public SecurityRoleEntity() {

    }

        getters and setters...
```

Here is the assembler class:

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {

        String username = userEntity.getUsername();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();
        boolean enabled = userEntity.getActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.getActive();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.getActive();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.getActive();

        Collection<GrantedAuthorityImpl> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthorityImpl>();

        for (SecurityRoleEntity role : userEntity.getSecurityRoleCollection()) {
            authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getName()));
        }

        User user = new User(username, password, enabled,
        accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);

        return user;

    }

}
```

Here is the content of my spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="service.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="assembler" class="service.Assembler">
</beans:bean>

<!-- <context:component-scan base-package="org.intan.pedigree" /> -->

<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="ROLE_User" />
    <!-- <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" 
        /> -->
</http>

<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Here is the UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserEntityDAO dao;

    @Autowired
    private Assembler assembler;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)

    throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        UserDetails userDetails = null;

        UserEntity userEntity = dao.findByName(username);

        if (userEntity == null)

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");

        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(userEntity);

    }

}
```

Here is the controller of the page I am trying to access:

```
public class HowDoesItWorkController implements Controller {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_User')")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.info("returning contact view");
    return new ModelAndView("/explain");
}

}
```

I have been following this tutorial:
http://giannisapi.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/spring-3-spring-security-implementing-custom-userdetails-with-hibernate/

Which says to insert those roles:

```
insert into security_role(name) values ("ROLE_admin");

insert into security_role(name) values ("ROLE_User");
```

I thought that the name of the role inserted in the DB should be the same as the one configured in the config file, so I changed the one in the xml file to fit the one in the DB but it doesn't change anything.

All other data in the DB seems to be good.

I also verified that the page I am trying to access is in /user and it is the case.

Comment: They do need to be matching values - it might be clearer if you update your post with the correct (matching) values, test that, and include any stack trace you see in your logs. Also check if you can access the page successfully _without_ security configured.

Comment: I updated my post with more information. I finally found out exactly where the problem is coming from but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. It appears that my UserEntity class doesn't load the user_security_role from the DB. The Set of UserSecurityRole is not being filled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem. It was my mistake, I was not using the good database under the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

The database that was configured here was referencing another database in which I also had the 3 tables, but because they were empty, no role were selected by the hibernate request.

Answer (score 0):

Your UserEntity's securityRoleCollection isn't being fetched when you call UserEntityDAO. findByName(). You either need to implement your DAO so it does a join fetch query (possibly more efficient) or the simple fix is to add:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<SecurityRoleEntity> securityRoleCollection
```

I don't think that's your only problem though. You still need to make sure all the role names are equal - your code above currently has:

```
ROLE_REGISTERED_USER
ROLE_User
```

They need to be the same (unless the SecurityRoleEntity class is mapping between the two?)

Comment: Thanks, it solved the LazyInitializationException but I know have the initial error I had: HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied. Having a closer look, it appears that for (SecurityRoleEntity role : userEntity.getSecurityRoleCollection()) in the buildUserFromUserEntity() method in the Assembler class return an empty Set of SecurityRoleCollection

Comment: I also fixed the role names so they are equals, I just forgot to update the post.

Comment: You don't show that class but it sounds like it also needs a FetchType.EAGER (or a join fetch query)

Comment: I added the Assembler class in the original post.

Comment: It's the SecurityRoleEntity class that's got the problem I think. Did you check for the FetchType.EAGER like I suggested? NOTE that you could also simplify this model - you don't need multiple entities if you just need to map a user to a list of role strings.

Comment: You are right, the SecurityRoleEntity class did not have the FetchType.EAGER for the private List<UserEntity> userCollection; but it doesn't solve the problem either. I added the updated class to the original post.

Comment: Now that I can see the class, you don't need that FetchType.EAGER...  Do your security_role table rows have an id? Your inserts only include the name.

Comment: Yes, it does have an ID that is auto incremented. Right now I have: 6  ROLE_User

Comment: I might be missing something in the @NamedQueries in the SecurityRoleEntity class.

Comment: Impossible to tell from the code you've posted - if you want help with queries include the code for your UserEntityDao so we can se how findByName() works

Comment: Are there any records in your user_security_role table?

Comment: Yes, I also verified that the user_id and role_id fit the data in the user and the security_role tables.

Comment: Try turning on hibernate logging so you can see exactly what query is executing when it calls UserEntityDAO.findByName() - it should be either joining and fetching the roles in one query, or running a query to load the user and another to load the roles

Comment: I tried to configure the logging.properties file of my tomcat, adding org.hibernate.type=debug but it does not change anything. I am using maven in eclipse, how should I proceed to configure the log level of hibernate?